# CSS Media Queries Font

Tags: css

I have viewed my page in every latest device available at the electronics shop.

I cant for the life of me get the fonts correct.  Whats massive in latest samsung galaxy is tiny in latest ipad etc etc.

```
body {

    font-size: 62.5%;
    line-height: 1.45em;
}
.p {
    font-size: 1.7em;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1280px) {
    .p {
        font-size: 1.842857142857143em;
    }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    .p {
        font-size: 1.842857142857143em;
    }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    .p {
        font-size: 2em;
    }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .p {
        font-size: 1.9em;
    }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {
    .p {
        font-size: 1.9em;
    }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {
    .p {
        font-size: 1.9em;
    }
}
```

What the hell am I doing wrong?

Please help.  Thanks

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking here because it's not clear what "correct" is.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Viewport to set the font size for many screen size.
here some info about it:

https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/

Browser support list:

http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units

Answer (score 0):

Wild guess: `.p` should be `p`. You're selecting a class rather than an element.